# Getting Java2OP to recognize new bridge files

Tags: android, delphi

I have updated Delphi to use the latest version of Google Play Services (Ver. 15.01). I downloaded the relevant libraries from Maven repository, extracted the files in the various jar files, merged them, and created a new jar library using jar.exe. I then ran it through Java2OP (after deleting the AndroidApi.JNI.PlayServices entry's in cache.txt). All of that is good and well, but now i want Java2OP to recognize my new play services bridge file. I made a little program to extract the definitions from my bridge file eg.

```
com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room Room {33C2F87B-37B5- 
47B7-8AFD-A69060142397} {8A130B18-A1B2-4529-8D5E-316D31507B72} 
AndroidAPI.JNI.PlayServices15
```

and replaced the Play Services entry's in cache.txt, but when i use Java2OP, i get errors:

```
com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room: not found
```

Does anybody have any expirience with this?

Comment: I have some experience with it, and would have a look at the problem however I haven't been able to find where to download the packages for com.google.android.gms.games

Comment: (https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=google+play+services)?

Comment: Can't see the games packages at that link

Comment: Something like [this](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/15.0.1/play-services-games-15.0.1.aar) or [this shorter version](https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/15.0.1/play-services-games-15.0.1.aar)?

Comment: Or, @Dave Nottage, even [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-games), which was in the list on the suggested Maven page if you went far enough down the list ;o)

Comment: Looks like Java2OP can't handle the .jar, which means it's possible that the JNI Bridge also won't be able to handle it at runtime. You could try your luck with Java2Pas: http://www.softwareunion.lu/en/downloads or Java Import: https://www.winsoft.sk/jimport.htm, or do it manually if you have a spare couple of weeks. You might like to file a report here: https://quality.embarcadero.com about Java2OP's problems

Comment: @Dave Nottage, would you care to share what type of errors/failures you encountered with Java2OP?

Comment: Failed to import the classes in question. Didn't even have them commented out; just did not import at all

Comment: @Dave Nottage. The Games library depends on other libraries, so you have extract these jar files (I used winrar), and then merge these files, and create a new jar using jar.exe. Java2OP can import this new jar.

Comment: Ah, of course.. thanks

Comment: You also need to remove the AndroidApi.JNI.PlayServices entry's from the cache.txt file (located with Java2OP.